# JSON String conversion to Dict

Tags: python, json

I'm having trouble converting the below JSON string to type dict.  json.loads throws an error because of the two sets of squiggles: {}, {}

```
test = '{"124074": "0.0944", "124111": "0.0809", "124194": "0.0788"}, {"128213": "0.39", "129043": "0.458", "129054": "0.378"}'
```

Any thoughts on how I fix this?  I need to be able to convert to dict so I can iterate through the keys.  Should the JSON string be represented in a different way?

Comment: Just do `json.loads("["+test+"]")`?

Comment: @gre_gor agreed, or `json.loads(f'[{test}]')` should do it

Comment: Since that's not valid JSON, it raises the question... is there a bug in whatever generated it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment from @rv.kvetch, one can get the following result

```
>>> test = '{"124074": "0.0944", "124111": "0.0809", "124194": "0.0788"}, {"128213": "0.39", "129043": "0.458", "129054": "0.378"}'
>>> dicts = json.loads(f'[{test}]')
>>> dicts
[{'124074': '0.0944', '124111': '0.0809', '124194': '0.0788'}, {'128213': '0.39', '129043': '0.458', '129054': '0.378'}]
>>> dicts[0]
{'124074': '0.0944', '124111': '0.0809', '124194': '0.0788'}
>>> type(dicts[0])
<class 'dict'>
```

essentially a list of dicts is created instead of a single dict.